# How to speed up walking animation of actors

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have many actors walking in the scene and I require them to walk a very long distance. They all seem to glide on the surface since the movement of their speed does not match the walking animation. Is there a way to speed up the walking animation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20138/how-to-speed-up-walking-animation-of-actors/) by [okan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2527/okan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 29 on 2018-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sorry to ask here before doing a quick search, but to synchronize the movement of the actor with the animation, we need to add following `<interpolate_x>true</interpolate_x>` tag in between `animation` tags.

For further detail refer to: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=actor

---

Originally posted by [okan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2527/okan/) with karma: 29 on 2018-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1